# Incorrect yaml format

Tags: python, yaml

```yaml
Title: "Covid19 Digest"
Section1: "What's new in this issue?"
Heading 1:
  - "North America"
  - Content:
    - "abc"
    - "def"
  - "Asia-Pacific"
  - Content:
    - "jkl"
    - subcontent:
      - "apples"
      - "oranges"
      - "oranges"
    - "mnop"
```

This Yaml file is mimicking a docx document. We have Title of the document and then different Sections. Each Section has heading 1 and under heading 1 is content in bulleted points. Problem with this is that it says the format is incorrect. I saw this tutorial
https://www.cloudbees.com/blog/yaml-tutorial-everything-you-need-get-started

And it seems to be working for them. How do I make a key under a key without making it a part of list? Such as Heading 1 should be under section 1. I can't hardcode stuff because number of heading 1 and sections are dynamic and so is the content

Comment: "it says the format is incorrect": what says this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want `"Heading1" to be a top-level key, you need to dedent it

```
Title: "Covid19 Digest"
Section1: "What's new in this issue?"
Heading 1:
         - "North America"
         - Content:
             - "abc"
             - "def"
         - "Asia-Pacific"
         - Content:
            - "jkl"
            - subcontent:
                - "apples"
                - "oranges"
                - "oranges"
            - "mnop"
```

If you want it to be a part of "Section 1", you need the thing under "Section 1" to be an object. Right now, it's a string. Consider something like

```
Title: "Covid19 Digest"
Section1:
  Title: "What's new in this issue?"
  Heading 1:
         - "North America"
         - Content:
             - "abc"
             - "def"
         - "Asia-Pacific"
         - Content:
            - "jkl"
            - subcontent:
                - "apples"
                - "oranges"
                - "oranges"
            - "mnop"
```

Comment: When reading it, is there any risk that contents of north ameria are swapped by contents of asia pacific?

Comment: `"North America"` and `"Asia-Pacific"` are strings; they don't have "contents" like an object would. If you want them to have contents, then they should be objects.

Comment: But they are generated dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

This is incorrect YAML:

```yaml
Section1: "What's new in this issue?"
  Heading 1:
```

What is the value of the key `Section1`? Is it `"What's new in this issue?"`? Is it the mapping starting with the key `Heading 1`? A key must have a single value, so you can't have both.

You can do something like

```
Section1:
  Title: "What's new in this issue?"
  Heading 1:
```